# How to lock or remove recovery options on an Android phone, specifically UleFone Armour X7 Pro?

Tags: security, recovery-mode, ulefone

At work, we have the Ulefone Armor X7 Pro to log activities and time. It is locked down by Hexnode for Work, but I was initially easily able to circumvent a lot of this by force-restating the phone (power off has been disabled), and when it starts up again, quickly open settings from the drop-down menu. Once the Settings app is open, Hexnode didn't block it. Through that, I was able to find the WiFi password of the company.

I told my manager about this vulnerability and he fixed my access to settings by disabling the dropdown menu with Hexnode. He also disabled the power button in Hexnode, but it doesn't really disable the button, rather, it just turned back on the screen if I put the phone to sleep. This drained everybody's battery and was no fix because I could still force restart it. Our IT guy seems to have no fix for this problem.

Does anybody know how I could block the restart option with some kind of code?

Comment: Don't your company pay Hexnode for their MDM solution, then I would first contact Hexnode for support if the offer protection options that don't work correctly.

Comment: @Robert      Sweet. I am a wee little noob that knows next to nothing about code, but somehow I was able to mess with a multi-million dollar company's security. I should have come to that idea myself; thank you for helping me gain in experience.

Answer (score 0):

I’m nowhere close to being an expert on this, but being a Hexnode user, what I’ve understood is that the “Disable Power Button” option is just meant to keep the screen awake. It isn’t intended to not make the button work. They also have a restriction to disable power off, but that depends on the manufacturer. I know that it is supported on Samsung Knox devices, don’t think that’s the case with Ulefone. This could have been better handled if the manufacturer supported OEM configurations.